# An accepted way to get Current.user in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a number of Rails engines in a Rails app, and each currently has its own constraint class to determine whether to allow the user

```
mount Flipper::UI.app(Flipper) => '/admin/flipper', :as => "feature_flags", constraints: CanAccessFeaturesUI
```

Since `Current.user` is set in the ApplicationController, it is not yet available in `routes.rb`.  Is there any accepted way to make it available to the router, so that I can simply do something roughly like this:

```
  mount Flipper::UI.app(Flipper) => '/admin/flipper', :as => "feature_flags", constraints: -> do
    Current&.user&.superuser?
  end
```

Comment: Did you consider [adding a custom middleware](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#adding-a-middleware) to your application which sets `Current.user` before Rails evaluates routes?

Comment: @spickermann: yes, that seems to be the best option!

Answer (score 4):

Details will depend on what you're using for authentication. For `devise`, one way would be to just not use `Current`:

```rb
# config/routes.rb

constraints ->(req) { req.env["warden"].user&.superuser? } do
  # TODO: secret routes
end
```

But `devise` has this feature built in:

```
authenticate :user, ->(user) { user.superuser? } do
  # TODO: secret routes
end
```

*https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/devise/4.9.2/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#authenticate-instance_method*

---

To use `Current` you need to set it in middleware. Because it runs right before routes:

```rb
$ bin/rails middleware
...
use Rack::ETag
use Rack::TempfileReaper
use Warden::Manager
# this is the place, after warden to use env["warden"]
#                   and before v
run Stackoverflow::Application.routes
```

```rb
# config/initializers/current_middleware.rb

class CurrentMiddleware
  def initialize app
    @app = app
  end

  def call env
    Current.user = env["warden"].user
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_after Warden::Manager, CurrentMiddleware
```

```rb
constraints -> { Current.user&.superuser? } do
  # TODO: secret routes
end
```